# Bizarre unittest behaviour, removing asserts leads to infinite loop

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm sorry for the length of this question, but there really is no other way to explain the bizarre behaviour I'm observing in the unittest module. My ambition is to give you all the necessary information to tell me what is going on here.

In a unittest class, I have a number of different test-functions. Two of them are:

```
def test_step_with_touching_but_not_colliding_balls(self):
    ## balls will not collide, but they will touch in the first moment.
    ## The problem here is that they are listed as touching with time 0,
    ## and thus the loop in step() is never exited.
    SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
    board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
    ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
    ball_2 = board.add_ball(r=50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 500+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600+ball_1.vy*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 650+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600+ball_2.vy*board.timestep)

    #########################################################################
    # We continue on the same setup.
    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 500+2*ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600+2*ball_1.vy*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 650+2*ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600+2*ball_2.vy*board.timestep)

    for i in range(25):
        board.step()

def test_step_colliding_balls_from_distance(self):
    SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
    board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
    ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 480, y = 600, vx = 10, vy = 0, m = 23)
    ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 700, y = 600, vx = -10, vy = 0, m = 23)

    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 480+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 700+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600)

    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 480+2*ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 700+2*ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600)
```

When I run the unittest with these two functions, I get the following:

```
    (balls) Sahands-MBP:src sahandzarrinkoub$ python test_boardmodel.py 
    ...................
```

I believe this to be an endless loop. If I do a `KeyboardInterrupt` I see this traceback:

```
  File "test_boardmodel.py", line 422, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/main.py", line 256, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 653, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "test_boardmodel.py", line 204, in test_step_with_touching_but_not_colliding_balls
    board.step()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/pythonfun/BouncingBalls/balls/src/model/boardmodel.py", line 96, in step
    object1.collide(object2)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/pythonfun/BouncingBalls/balls/src/model/boardmodel.py", line 349, in collide
    self.collide_with_ball(other)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/pythonfun/BouncingBalls/balls/src/model/boardmodel.py", line 441, in collide_with_ball
    ])*((r1+r2)/((x2-x1)**2-(y2-y1)**2))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Fair enough, I think. But there is one very weird behaviour that I cannot explain. If I comment out the last four lines of that code snippet above, the test finishes fine. So to be clear, I change the above excerpt to this:

```
def test_step_with_touching_but_not_colliding_balls(self):
    ## balls will not collide, but they will touch in the first moment.
    ## The problem here is that they are listed as touching with time 0,
    ## and thus the loop in step() is never exited.
    SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
    board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
    ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
    ball_2 = board.add_ball(r=50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 500+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600+ball_1.vy*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 650+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600+ball_2.vy*board.timestep)



#########################################################################
    # We continue on the same setup.
    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 500+2*ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600+2*ball_1.vy*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 650+2*ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600+2*ball_2.vy*board.timestep)

    for i in range(25):
        board.step()

def test_step_colliding_balls_from_distance(self):
    SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
    board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
    ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 480, y = 600, vx = 10, vy = 0, m = 23)
    ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 700, y = 600, vx = -10, vy = 0, m = 23)

    board.step()

    self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 480+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 700+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600)
    self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600)

    board.step()

    # self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 480+2*ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
    # self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 700+2*ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
    # self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600)
    # self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600)
```

And when I run the test I see this:

```
......................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 0.009s

OK
```

I think this is bizarre, because the four lines that have been commented out don't lead to any code execution inside of the classes being tested.

Also, the infinite loop isn't even occuring in the same function where the lines were commented out!

As you can see from the traceback, the infinite loop occurs inside of either the `Ball` or the `Board` classes. How could commenting out 4 asserts that simply check the values of object attributes have such a dramatic impact on the test?

EDIT: Since a user suggested I should look for errors in the test class, here is the entire thing. I can not find anything wrong with it, but maybe I'm missing something.

```
import unittest

from model.boardmodel import Board, Ball, Wall
from model.exceptions.exceptions import ProximityError

class BoardModelMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def assertRaisesWithMessage(self, msg, func, *args, **kwargs):
        try:    
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.assertFail()
        except Exception as inst:
            self.assertEqual(inst.message, msg)

    def test_collide_ball_wall(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 2)

        ball = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 90, r = 10, vx = 0, vy = 1, m = 1)
        ball.collide(Wall(board, 1)) # Collide with upper wall
        self.assertEqual(ball.vx, 0) # Should be unchanged
        self.assertEqual(ball.vy, -1) # Should be inverted

        ball = board.add_ball(x = 90, y = 50, r = 10, vx = 1, vy = 1, m = 1)
        ball.collide(Wall(board, 2)) # Collide with right wall
        self.assertEqual(ball.vx, -1) # Should be inverted
        self.assertEqual(ball.vy, 1) # Should be unchanged

        ball = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 10, r = 10, vx = 1, vy = -1, m = 1)
        ball.collide(Wall(board, 3)) # Collide with bottom wall
        self.assertEqual(ball.vx, 1) # Should be unchanged
        self.assertEqual(ball.vy, 1) # Should be inverted       

        ball = board.add_ball(x = 10, y = 50, r = 10, vx = -1, vy = 1, m = 1)
        ball.collide(Wall(board, 4)) # Collide with left wall
        self.assertEqual(ball.vx, 1) # Should be inverted
        self.assertEqual(ball.vy, 1) # Should be unchanged  

        with self.assertRaises(ProximityError):
            ball = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 50, r = 10, vx = 1, vy = 1, m = 1)
            ball.collide(Wall(board, 1)) # This shouldn't work


    def test_collide_ball_ball(self):

        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 45, y = 50, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 0, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 55, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = 0, m = 1)

        ball_1.collide(ball_2)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 45)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 55)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 50)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 50)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.r, 5)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.r, 5)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.vx, 2)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.vx, -2)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.vy, 0)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.vy, 0)


        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100) # Same thing with one line changed
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 45, y = 50, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 0, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 55, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = 0, m = 1)

        ball_2.collide(ball_1) # This line is changed

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 45)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 55)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 50)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 50)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.r, 5)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.r, 5)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.vx, 2)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.vx, -2)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.vy, 0)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.vy, 0)


        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100) # Testing something not as straight and not as symmetrical...
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 45, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 1, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 55, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = -10, m = 1)

        ball_1.collide(ball_2)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.vx, 2.0)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.vx, -2.0)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.vy, -10.0)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.vy, 1.0)

    def test_get_balls_pygame(self):
        ########################################################################
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100)
        board.add_ball(r=1, x = 50, y = 50, vx = 10, vy = 10)
        pygame_balls = board.get_balls_pygame()

        for ball in pygame_balls:
            for val in ball.values():
                self.assertIsInstance(val, int)

        self.assertEqual(pygame_balls, [{'r':1, 'x':50, 'y':50}])

        del board

        ########################################################################
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)

        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 10, y = 10, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 2, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = -2, m = 1)

        board.step()
        self.assertEqual(board.time_elapsed, 1)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 12)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 12)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 48)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 48)
        balls = board.get_balls_pygame()
        self.assertEqual(len(balls), len(board.get_ball_list()))

        pygame_balls = board.get_balls_pygame()
        ball_list = board.get_ball_list()

        for ball in pygame_balls:
            for val in ball.values():
                self.assertIsInstance(val, int)


        for r in map(lambda x: x['r'], pygame_balls):
            self.assertIn(r, map(lambda x: x.r, ball_list))

        for x in map(lambda x: x['x'], pygame_balls):
            self.assertIn(x, map(lambda x: x.x, ball_list))

        for y in map(lambda x: x['y'], pygame_balls):
            self.assertIn(x, map(lambda x: x.y, ball_list))

    def test_step_without_balls(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)

        #Take step without balls
        board.step()
        #Test that time is progressed by a timestep
        self.assertEqual(board.time_elapsed, 1)

    def test_step_with_balls(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)

        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 10, y = 10, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 2, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = -2, m = 1)

        board.step()
        self.assertEqual(board.time_elapsed, 1)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 12)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 12)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 48)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 48)
        balls = board.get_balls_pygame()
        self.assertEqual(len(balls), len(board.get_ball_list()))

        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 900, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r=50, x = 600, y = 400, vx = 40, vy = -20, m = 10)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 900+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 600+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)

    def test_step_with_touching_but_not_colliding_balls(self):
        ## balls will not collide, but they will touch in the first moment.
        ## The problem here is that they are listed as touching with time 0,
        ## and thus the loop in step() is never exited.
        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r=50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 500+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600+ball_1.vy*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 650+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600+ball_2.vy*board.timestep)

        #########################################################################
        # We continue on the same setup.
        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 500+2*ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600+2*ball_1.vy*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 650+2*ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600+2*ball_2.vy*board.timestep)

        for i in range(25):
            board.step()

    def test_step_colliding_balls_from_distance(self):
        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 480, y = 600, vx = 10, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 700, y = 600, vx = -10, vy = 0, m = 23)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 480+ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 700+ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600)

        board.step()

        # self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 480+2*ball_1.vx*board.timestep)
        # self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 700+2*ball_2.vx*board.timestep)
        # self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 600)
        # self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 600)

    def test_add_ball(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)

        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 10, y = 10, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 2, m = 1)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1, board.get_ball_list()[0])

    def test_progress_balls(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)

        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 10, y = 10, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 2, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = -2, m = 1)

        board.progress_balls(2)

        self.assertEqual(ball_1.x, 14)
        self.assertEqual(ball_1.y, 14)

        self.assertEqual(ball_2.x, 46)
        self.assertEqual(ball_2.y, 46)

    def test_collide_wall_1(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 70, r = 10, vx = 0, vy = 1, m = 1)

        for i in range(20):
            board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.y, 90)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.y, 89)

    def test_collide_wall_2(self):
        board = Board(width = 1000, height = 1000, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 800, y = 100, r = 100, vx = 10, vy = 0, m = 1)        

        for i in range(10):
            board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.x, 900)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.x, 890)

    def test_collide_wall_3(self):
        board = Board(width = 1000, height = 1000, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 500, y = 200, r = 100, vx = 0, vy = -10, m = 1)

        for i in range(10):
            board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.y, 100)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.y, 110)

    def test_collide_wall_4(self):
        board = Board(width = 1000, height = 1000, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 200, y = 500, r = 100, vx = -10, vy = 0, m = 1)

        for i in range(10):
            board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.x, 100)

        board.step()

        self.assertEqual(ball.x, 110)

    def test_first_wall_contacts_wall_1(self):
        ## ball is touching wall
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 90, r = 10, vx = 0, vy = 1, m = 1)

        contacts = board.first_wall_contacts(1)

        collidors = contacts['collidors']

        self.assertEqual(collidors, [(ball,board.walls[1])])


    def test_first_wall_contacts_wall_2(self):
        ## ball is touching wall
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 90, y = 50, r = 10, vx = 1, vy = 0, m = 1)
        contacts = board.first_wall_contacts(1)

        collidors = contacts['collidors']

        self.assertEqual(collidors, [(ball,board.walls[2])])

    def test_first_wall_contacts_wall_3(self):
        ## ball is touching wall
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 50, y = 10, r = 10, vx = 0, vy = -1, m = 1)

        contacts = board.first_wall_contacts(1)

        collidors = contacts['collidors']

        self.assertEqual(collidors, [(ball,board.walls[3])])

    def test_first_wall_contacts_wall_4(self):
        ## ball is touching wall
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1)
        ball = board.add_ball(x = 10, y = 50, r = 10, vx = -1, vy = 0, m = 1)

        contacts = board.first_wall_contacts(1)

        collidors = contacts['collidors']

        self.assertEqual(collidors, [(ball,board.walls[4])])

    def test_first_wall_contacts_no_contact_with_wall(self):

        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

        wall_contacts = board.first_wall_contacts(1)

        self.assertEqual(wall_contacts, None)
        self.assertEqual(wall_contacts, None)

    def test_first_ball_contacts_2_balls(self):

        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1) # Same thing with one line changed
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 45, y = 50, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 0, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 55, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = 0, m = 1)

        contacts = board.first_ball_contacts(1)
        self.assertEqual(contacts['time'], 0)
        self.assertEqual(len(contacts['collidors'][0]), 2)
        self.assertEqual(board.get_ball_list(), list(contacts['collidors'][0]))

        balls = board.get_balls_pygame()
        self.assertEqual(len(balls), 2)

        ###################################################################
        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

        contacts = board.first_ball_contacts(board.timestep)
        self.assertEqual(contacts, None)


    def test_collision_time(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1) # Same thing with one line changed
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 45, y = 50, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 0, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 55, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = 0, m = 1)

        tc = board.t_collision(ball_1, ball_2)

        t = board.collision_time(ball_1, ball_2, 1)
        self.assertEqual(t, 0)

        ###################################################################
        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

        t = board.collision_time(ball_1, ball_2, 1)
        self.assertEqual(t, None)

    def test_t_collision(self):
        board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1) # Same thing with one line changed
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 45, y = 50, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 0, m = 1)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 55, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = 0, m = 1)

        t = board.t_collision(ball_1, ball_2)
        self.assertEqual(t, 0)

        ###################################################################
        SCREEN_RES = {'width':1100, 'height':800}
        board = Board(**SCREEN_RES)
        ball_1 = board.add_ball(r = 100, x = 500, y = 600, vx = 20, vy = 0, m = 23)
        ball_2 = board.add_ball(r = 50, x = 650, y = 600, vx = 40, vy = 0, m = 10)

        t = board.t_collision(ball_1, ball_2)
        self.assertEqual(t, None)

    def test_ball__str__(self):
        board = Board()
        ball = Ball(parent = board, xpos = 50, ypos = 50, radius = 100, vx = 0, vy = 0, mass = 1)
        self.assertEqual(str(ball), "Ball: x={0}, y={1}, r={2}, vx={3}, vy={4}".format(ball.x,ball.y,ball.r,ball.vx,ball.vy))





if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: It's probably not the commented-out lines. You most likely made some other change you didn't notice, such as an indentation change. Consider looking for mixed tabs and spaces or other indentation issues.

Comment: There are no mixed tabs and spaces. And if I uncomment the lines I get the same infinite loop again...

Comment: Well, your *post* has a mixture of tabs and spaces that suggests that either your real code also had tabs-and-spaces problems, or you didn't actually copy the second snippet out of a version of your code you actually ran.

Comment: I've searched through all of the code for the tests with CMD+F and every single indentation is done with tabs.

Comment: Maybe there is some interaction between the Board and Ball objects between the different test functions?

Comment: Could be, especially if you have weird property getters.

Comment: But isn't each test function separated? Meaning all objects created in each test function are deleted after function completion?